# Is is possible to display barcharts horizontally in Flot?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, bar-chart

Apologies, but I'm a newbie at Flot.

I'd like to display my data in a horizontal bar chart rather a vertical bar chart which Flot seems to default to.

Is it possible to do this in Flot, and, if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
bars: {
      horizontal: true
    }
```

API reference: http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt

Comment: oops. oh yeah. protovis is still worth checking out

Comment: I'll take a look, but we're pretty in bed with flot here. A lot of sparkline style charts and multiaxis JSON driven charts. Would take forever to change. Doesn't seem to work in IE7 though?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I tried this and yes, it works.  The only problem though is that I have to change the x and y-axes data.

Answer (score 2):

For an example of a horizontal bar chart built with Flot, check out
http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-horizontal-bar-chart.html